# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<library.package.class> on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, docx4j

I am trying to generate PDF/Docx in android.

I tried with a lot of libraries: apache poi, docx4j and pdf box but always have this message in the console.

Any idea?

For example for this example code for docx4j:

```
public class ExportNotebookToWordTask extends RoboAsyncTask<Void> {

        private ProgressDialog exportProgress;
        private Activity activity;

        protected ExportNotebookToWordTask (Context context, Activity activity) {
            super(context);
            this.activity = activity;
            exportProgress = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            exportProgress.setIndeterminate(true);
            exportProgress.setCancelable(false);
            exportProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            exportProgress.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.export_notebook_to_pdf_progress));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() throws Exception {
            super.onPreExecute();
            exportProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {

            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
            wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("Hello Word!");

            File notebookDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + Constants.NOTEBOOKS_DIR);
            if(!notebookDir.exists()) {
                notebookDir.mkdir();
            }
            wordMLPackage.save(new File(notebookDir, course.getName() + Constants.DOCX_EXTENSION_FILE));

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSuccess(Void result) throws Exception {
            super.onSuccess(result);
            DigitalNotebookActivity.this.finish();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onFinally() throws RuntimeException {
            super.onFinally();
            if (exportProgress != null && exportProgress.isShowing()) {
                exportProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

Log:

```
05-25 22:41:42.927  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting
re-init on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler> 05-25
22:41:42.927  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init
on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler> 05-25
22:41:42.957  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init
on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler> 05-25
22:41:42.977  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init
on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler> 05-25
22:41:43.027  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/System.out﹕
22:41:43.041 [pool-4-thread-8] INFO  org.docx4j.jaxb.Context -
java.vendor=The Android Project 05-25 22:41:43.027 
29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/System.out﹕ 22:41:43.043
[pool-4-thread-8] INFO  org.docx4j.jaxb.Context - java.version=0 05-25
22:41:43.137  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/System.out﹕
22:41:43.152 [pool-4-thread-8] DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils -
Attempting to load: org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties 05-25 22:41:43.147 
29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/System.out﹕ 22:41:43.160
[pool-4-thread-8] DEBUG org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils - Not using
MOXy, since no resource: org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties 05-25
22:41:43.147  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/System.out﹕
22:41:43.161 [pool-4-thread-8] INFO  org.docx4j.jaxb.Context - No MOXy
JAXB config found; assume not intended.. 05-25 22:41:43.147 
29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/System.out﹕ 22:41:43.161
[pool-4-thread-8] DEBUG org.docx4j.jaxb.Context -
org/docx4j/wml/jaxb.properties not found via classloader. 05-25
22:41:43.147  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init
on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperSunInternal>
05-25 22:41:43.157  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting
re-init on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperSunInternal>
05-25 22:41:43.157  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting
re-init on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapper> 05-25
22:41:43.157  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init
on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapper> 05-25
22:41:43.157  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init
on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperRelationshipsPartSunInternal>
05-25 22:41:43.157  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting
re-init on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperRelationshipsPartSunInternal>
05-25 22:41:43.177  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting
re-init on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperRelationshipsPart>
05-25 22:41:43.177  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting
re-init on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperRelationshipsPart>
05-25 22:41:43.177  29302-31419/com.digitalnotebook I/art﹕ Rejecting
re-init on previously-failed class
java.lang.Class<org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapper>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have met the similar issue that was caused by failing to init a static member variable.

```
private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff \t"); // fff is a wrong format, it should be SSS.
```

I guess instantiation errors or dependency errors cause this kind of exceptions.